# How and why does this code work?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, traits

My question is based on [Data Viewer with Laravel 5.3 and Vue.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f5BbiyrPs8)

This dude creates a trait DataViewer and codes it similar to following:

```
trait DataViewer 
{
    // $query should be a Query Builder
    public function scopePaginateAndOrder($query)
    {
        // Validation ...

        // Where, Pagination, Order etc ...
        return $query->where('foo', 'like', 'bar');
    }
}
```

Now you can use this trait in any Eloquent Model to add search functionality.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use DataViewer;
}
```

Everything usual stuff, nothing special ...
but then there is some "magic" i did't see in PHP yet.

In a controller he does something like

```
$model = App\Customer::paginateAndOrder();
```

The last code snippet does have many aspects i can't understand.

1. Why can i call this non-static-method in a static-method way using **::**?
2. Why can i omit the **scope** from the method name?
3. I don't have to pass a Query Builder object as parameter. So how does the trait "know" on which model i want to paginate/order

Thanks for your help folks!

Comment: `I don't have to pass a Query Builder object as parameter` and `// $query should be a Query Builder` is bad practise (should/can/...). Why does the function not look like this: `public function scopePaginateAndOrder(QueryBuilder $query = null)` ?   On `1.` it will throw a note/warning in php `Strict standards: Non-static method` but the meothod will be called. What do you mean with `2.`?

Comment: And by the way: Once you talk about `scopePaginateAndOrder` then about  `paginateAndOrder`, there will be 2 diff. method called, not the same. so you can not omit the 'scope' when you try to call `scopePaginateAndOrder()`. Something other is going wrong in your logic.

Comment: Ok, not type hinting a parameter is indeed a bad practise, i just did a copy and paste from the above linked video. And yes i have to use paginateAndOrder() INSTEAD of scopePaginateAndOrder() otherwise it will throw an exception

Comment: Is that someone you fully belive on youtube?   Last what i have to note: Traits  are so ugly, breaking any good OOP concept, with injecting code without any rules at all. Use them wisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel makes good use of a few of PHP's magic methods, specifically in this case `__call()` and `__callStatic`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

With `callStatic`, if a static method is called that either doesn't exists or is inaccessible then the call will be delegated to the `__callStatic()` method in that class (if one exists). The same is true `__call()` and instance methods.

If you look in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` you'll find:

```
/**
 * Handle dynamic method calls into the model.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $parameters);
    }

    $query = $this->newQuery();

    return call_user_func_array([$query, $method], $parameters);
}

/**
 * Handle dynamic static method calls into the method.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    $instance = new static;

    return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $parameters);
}
```

In the above, if `__callStatic` is invoked then it will create a `new` instance of the model and try and call the method on that instance, so when you call `App\Customer::paginateAndOrder()` it will then try and call `paginateAndOrder()` as an instance method.

(Not included `increment` and `decrement`) The `__call()` method on the model will then try and call that method on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. `Builder` then has it's own `__call()` method which has the following in it:

```
if (method_exists($this->model, $scope = 'scope' . ucfirst($method))) {
    return $this->callScope([$this->model, $scope], $parameters);
}
```

`callScope` then just call the actual `scopePaginateAndOrder` and passes the `Builder` through.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is the magic of Laravel.. not php at all.

Laravel utilizes what's known with [magic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic)

> 1. Why can i call this non-static-method in a static-method way using ::?

I will only list two here `__call()` and `__callStatic()`, these functions are called when you call non-existent non-static an static functions respectively..

So in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` which is the super class for all models does this, check this [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1326).

> 2. Why can i omit the scope from the method name?'

Simply Laravel allows you to omit prefixes  of function names that represent what it does. eg. the `scope` prefix in your case.. And keeps adding the prefixes in a specific order till it finds it.
Read the [code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L1302) if you want a closer look.

> 3. I don't have to pass a Query Builder object as parameter. So how does the trait "know" on which model i want to paginate/order

I believe this is due to Laravel IoC container and dependcy injection..

Note: Q3 needs more research to be sure when & how the injection is made.